# Kubernetes -> Memory consumption per namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to get the memory consumption per namespace on Kubernetes?

Comment: You can find all requested information and more in Kubernetes docs:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-memory-cpu-namespace/

Answer (score 3):

**On high level we can get this from kubectl**

$ kubectl describe resourcequota -n my-namespace

```
Name:            compute-resources
Namespace:       default
Resource         Used    Hard
--------         ----    ----
limits.cpu       12      48
limits.memory    1024M   120Gi
requests.cpu     250m    24
requests.memory  512M    60Gi
```

**Note : will work only if your create resourcequota.**

Answer (score 0):

It's possible creating a resourcequota object like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: mem-cpu-demo
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "1"
    requests.memory: 1Gi
    limits.cpu: "2"
    limits.memory: 2Gi
```

However there are some pre requisites in order to check the pods consumption:

1. Every Container must have a memory request, memory limit, cpu
   request, and cpu limit.
2. The memory request total for all Containers must not exceed 1 GiB.
3. The memory limit total for all Containers must not exceed 2 GiB.
4. The CPU request total for all Containers must not exceed 1 cpu.
5. The CPU limit total for all Containers must not exceed 2 cpu.

Pod example template

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: quota-mem-cpu-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: quota-mem-cpu-demo-ctr
    image: nginx
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "800Mi"
        cpu: "800m" 
      requests:
        memory: "600Mi"
        cpu: "400m"
```

To check the resource consumption use the following command:

```
kubectl --context <cluster_context> describe resourcequota -n my-namespace
```

Source:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-memory-cpu-namespace/